# PHP Form Submitting Undefined Values

Tags: php, html, forms

Like my title says, my email form is submitting "undefined" within the email. Let me start off with some code...

HTML:

```
<form action="contactform.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="contact">
        <input name="name" type="text" value="Name" onfocus="if(this.value=='Name') this.value='';" />
        <input name="email" type="text" value="Email address" onfocus="if(this.value=='Email address') this.value='';" />
        <input name="phonemodel" type="text" value="Phone model" onfocus="if(this.value=='Phone model') this.value='';" />
        <textarea name="comments" cols="" rows="" style="height:130px;" onfocus="if(this.value=='Type your message here.') this.value='';" >Type your message here.</textarea>
        <input type="image" name="button" value="Submit" src="../media/btn_play_submit.png" style="margin-right:5px; margin-top:12px;" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['name'])) {

    $to = 'MYEMAILHERE';
    $headers = "From: blahblahblah\r\n";
    $subject = "Online Contact Submission Received\r\n";

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phonemodel'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

    $message .= "Name: " . $name . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Email: " . $email . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Phone Model: " . $phone . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Comments: " . $comments . "\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  }
?>
```

The email that I receive looks like this (and yes, I'm putting text in the fields...):

```
Name: undefined
Email: undefined
Phone Model:
Comments: undefined
```

First thing I notice: the "Phone Model" does not say "undefined" like the others. Second, why are the others saying undefined instead of the text I put in?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show us the source of the received email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Turns out it was going through some jQuery and then AJAX before getting to the PHP which is what was causing all of my problems.

This is what happens when you get thrown into a project and don't quite understand it. :/

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing

`$message .= "Name: " . $name . "\r\n";`

to

`$message = "Name: " . $name . "\r\n";`

EDIT: sample below:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    var_dump($_POST);
    exit;
```

Comment: hmm. Try `var_dump($_POST)` at the op of your script and see what it contains

Comment: Do this Right after `if(isset($_POST['name'])) {` `var_dump($_POST); exit;`

Comment: Right, but where does it dump? I'm using Espresso - should I be using something else to see the dump?

Comment: See my edit above. It simple prints the contents on `$POST` to the secrren. You'll need to exit the script to see it.

Comment: Looks good. `array(7) { ["name"]=> string(3) "fds" ["email"]=> string(3) "fds" ["phonemodel"]=> string(3) "fds" ["comments"]=> string(3) "fds" ["button_x"]=> string(2) "49" ["button_y"]=> string(2) "18" ["button"]=> string(6) "Submit" }`

Comment: What email client are you using when you receive the email?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the line breaks "\r\n" after the headers and subject, they could be screwing with the mail function.

```
$headers = "From: blahblahblah\r\n";
$subject = "Online Contact Submission Received\r\n";
```

To:

```
$headers = "From: blahblahblah";
$subject = "Online Contact Submission Received";
```

If the doesn't do it, dump your $_POST array and check if it gets the the form handler.

Comment: For the record, I did add the last part of my answer BEFORE I saw Paul's comment on his answer.

Comment: Still undefined. Where does it dump to when I dump it? I'm an iOS dev forced to do web for the week. :X

Comment: var_dump should output it to the browser

Comment: Looks good. `array(7) { ["name"]=> string(3) "fds" ["email"]=> string(3) "fds" ["phonemodel"]=> string(3) "fds" ["comments"]=> string(3) "fds" ["button_x"]=> string(2) "49" ["button_y"]=> string(2) "18" ["button"]=> string(6) "Submit" }`

Answer (score 1):

First simply print these variables to narrow down the issue.
When its not properly printed. Try using GET instead $_POST['xxx'] -> $_GET['xxx'], method='post' -> method='get'
Of course its not what you want, just to make sure.

There are options in webservers to disable GET and/or POST. Do you test on a fresh unconfigured server?

Answer (score 1):

### Update

It appears that you are using something other than HTML & PHP to run your web site / form.  Are there any other libraries, in either PHP or Javascript, that might be touching this before your script does?

### Original

You should to change your form `enctype` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` unless you're submitting `files, non-ASCII data, and binary data` as per [the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.3).

`multipart/form-data` is going to give you strange behavior otherwise.  At least, that's been my unequivocal experience.

Comment: Nothing. :/ What a pain this is becoming.

Answer (score 1):

Besides all above solutions, you can use `placeholder="text you want to display"` inplace of `onfocus="if(this.value=='Name') this.value='';"`. May be something went wrong with the values there ....

Answer (score 0):

When you reference local files, put those references in this order:

- CSS of mobile

  JS of jQuery core

  JS of jQuery mobile.

Out of place would cause this error

**correct**:

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jq-all-debug.js"> 

        <script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js">
```

**wrong**:

```
        <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"> 

<script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"> 

                <script type="text/javascript" src="jq-all-debug.js">
```